# Cannot connect to remote site: Authentication to web service failed

Tags: nagios, check-mk

I've installed Check_MK 1.2.8p9 (an open monitoring distribution of Nagios) on two servers and I'm attempting to connect the second host to the master. On the Distributed Monitoring WATO page I've added the second host as a slave.

When I click the "Login" button and enter the "Administrator name" and "Administrator password" I get the error:

> Cannot connect to remote site: Authentication to web service failed. Message: Check_MK Multisite Login 1.2.8p9 Username: Password: Version: 1.2.8p9 - © Mathias Kettner You can use, modify and distribute Check_MK under the terms of the GNU GPL Version 2.

I can however log into either Check_MK instance with the same Administrator name and Administrator password that I am supplying.

Any thoughts/ideas on how to set up this distributed monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps. This person needed to set up the automated user.

https://monitoring-portal.org/index.php?thread/32744-can-t-replicate-configuration-on-distributed-wato-login-failed/

Sounds like the user configuration needs checked.

Also check folder permissions for the users you are using. I've seen mention of a file htpasswd.users  permissions being incorrect.